# The == is not working in my IF statement Function

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

i have a simple function (up) here its an arrow and onclick is should check for image 1 in the div "gallerymain" and if its there it should show image 2.   ELSE if image 3 is displayed and it suppose to show image 4 .

however for some unknown reason the == isn't  working (i checked with alert ) , i also made sure that all is in the right case and path . the funny thing is that if i will use = instead of == it will work but it onclick it will show image 2 no matter what (even if image 3 is there ) i understand why (because i am assigning the path to the src .  maybe somebody please take a fresh look on it and see what am i missing.

thank you!

```
  function up () {         


     if 
        (document.getElementById("gallerymain").src == 
    "../images/gallery/image1.jpg") 
        {
        document.getElementById("gallerymain").src = 
    "../images/gallery/image2.jpg"
        }
    else if   
    (document.getElementById("gallerymain").src == 
    "../images/gallery/image3.jpg") 
        {
    document.getElementById("gallerymain").src = 
    "../images/gallery/image4.jpg"
        }
    }
```

Comment: try `console.log(document.getElementById("gallerymain").src)` before the `if` - what does it output

Comment: `the funny thing is` no, it's not funny ... because `=` is assignment, and if you're assigning a truthy value (such as a non-empty string), the condition will be truthy

Comment: just as an aside, to make your code less repetitive, more readable and shorter ... https://pastebin.com/iEQjXhJ7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`img.src` *getter* (as in `img.src == '../img.jpg'`) returns **absolute URL** that is `http://mysite.dev/img.jpg`. `img.src` *setter* (as in `img.src = '../img.jpg'`) amends **relative URL** to absolute.
`getAttribute` method returns exactly what was assigned. So try this.

```
if 
    (document.getElementById("gallerymain").getAttribute('src') == 
"../images/gallery/image1.jpg") 
    {
    document.getElementById("gallerymain").src = 
"../images/gallery/image2.jpg"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir!!! i a new to JS and was trying to figure it for days!! it works perfectly fine !! "Spaibo bolshoe!"